# Kobo Glo Running Android

Tags: custom-roms, device-firmware, kobo

I recently bought a Kobo Glo, and while carelessly googling around, stumbled into this:
 http://www.engadget.com/2013/11/04/kobo-glo-android-hack/

1) Has any of the fellow SE-Android-lings attempted / succeded installing android on the Kobo Glo?

2) How can I backup the Original Firmware of the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering question #2 only, since I don't own the reader.

According to [this post](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showpost.php?p=2676872&postcount=43) on the source thread, the original firmware can remain intact if you simply use a different microSD Card to load Android on:

> You can dual-boot by having two separate MicroSDcards, one for each
>   system, and swap them. You will have to open the back of your glo each
>   time though.
>
> See the first 10 photos at http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showpost.php?p=2462848&postcount=2

Comment: Oh boy, this is awesome. Does it means the Kobo Glo is expansible to 64GB (since it has an external SD slot too)? it would be insane.  Also, I will wait a couple more days @chahk to see if someone answers #1, if not i will accept yours.

Comment: @Mindwin that depends if the card reader inside the tablet supports SDXC technology required by most 64GB cards. If you scroll down and view the other pictures on that link I posted, you'll see that they managed to upgrade to 32GB.

Comment: I was thinking of 32GB on the inner slot and another 32GB on the outside slot. XD